# Calculating percentile from django queryset

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Let's say I have a django queryset of objects `User`. Each `User` has an `average_score`. How can I determine the user's percentile (top 10%, top 20%, etc) based on the `average_score`?

If I were able to sort the queryset, I could theoretically take the index divided by the total count (eg 5th place out of 100 total is top 5%) but since we can't sort querysets– what can I do here?

Answer (score 1):

Updated snippet to take into account possible division by zero error.
It gets the number of objects with `average_score` less than specified using __lte queryset filter ([Less than or equal to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#lte)) and divided by the total number of objects in the database.

Everything is done on the database end, and (almost) no data is transferred back and forth, so it should work efficiently even with large number of user objects in the database

```
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    total_count = queryset.count()
    if total_count:
        percentile = float(queryset.filter(average_score__lte=average_score).count())/total_count
    else:
        return 0.0
```

Comment: Be careful about division by zero !!  Your snippet don't catch this error.

Comment: Right, I will update the snippet. This shouldn't happen, though - average_score comes from a User object so there will be at least one object in the database.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python Just a SO post about EAFP principe. Used in Sanca answer. More pytonic.

Answer (score 1):

few months ago, i had a similiar problem to find average transactions for this year, such as script below. hopefully can help..

```
import time
from django import template
from yourapp.models import Transaction

register = template.Library()
now_year = time.strftime("%Y")

@register.simple_tag
def graph_average_income_by_year():

    try:
        transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(paid=True)\
                                          .filter(payment_date__year=now_year)
        count_transactions = transactions.count()
        incomes = [ p.total_transfer for p in transactions ]
        return ("%.1f" % (float(sum(incomes))/count_transactions) )
    except:
        return 0.0
```